# Django Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have looked for other answers but cannot get this one working.
I have model `Sitting` with a field `user_answers` which stores a dictionary

```
{"437": "1574", "319": "hi", "383": "1428", "424": "1528", "203": "785"}
```

When I do

```
 {% for key, value in sitting %}
    <p> {{key}}--{{value}} </p>
    <p> {{question.id}}--{{answer.id}} </p>
        {% ifequal key question.id %}
            {% ifequal  value answer.id %}
                <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers" >
                <span><label for="id_answers_0"><input type="radio" name="answers_{{question.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}" style="margin-right:10px;" id="{{answer.id}}" selected required>
                {{answer.content}}  </label>  </span></li>  
            {% else %}    
            <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers" >
                <span><label for="id_answers_0"><input type="radio" name="answers_{{question.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}" style="margin-right:10px;" id="{{answer.id}}"  required>
                {{answer.content}}  </label>  </span></li>   
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the error
`Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1`.

How can I compare the values so I can select the radio if the key and value matches the question and answer?

**Update**
{{sitting.items}} in template shows this

{"424": "1529", "437": "1573", "203": "786", "383": "1427", "319": "hi"}

However, when I

```
{% for key, value in sitting.items %}
                            <p> {{key}}--{{value}} </p>
                            <p> {{question.id}}--{{answer.id}} </p>
                                {% ifequal key question.id %}
                                    {% ifequal  value answer.id %}
                                        <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers" >
                                        <span><label for="id_answers_0"><input type="radio" name="answers_{{question.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}" style="margin-right:10px;" id="{{answer.id}}" selected required>
                                        {{answer.content}}  </label>  </span></li>  
                                    {% else %}    
                                    <li class="list-group-item quiz-answers" >
                                        <span><label for="id_answers_0"><input type="radio" name="answers_{{question.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}" style="margin-right:10px;" id="{{answer.id}}"  required>
                                        {{answer.content}}  </label>  </span></li>   
                             {% endifequal %}
              {% endifequal %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Nothing seems to happpen.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

`{% for key, value in sitting.items %}`

You need to provide `.items` when iterating over a dictionary from Python. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it somehow does not seem to work. {{sitting}} displays in template. {{sitting.items}} does not display anything and the for loop does not work. I tried changing the views.py to sitting = Sitting.objects.filter(id=self.sitting.id).values_list('user_answers',flat=True)[0]

Comment: @stackoverflowrohit Can you include the view and model you're using to display this template? Seeing the context will be a big help.